# Symmetric product of global sections on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a complete curve defined over complex number, $D$ a effective divisor on $C$, and
$V\subseteq H^0(D)$ a subspace. Assume that $V$ is base-point-free, which means that the zero of the sections in $V$ do not have common point. Consider the canonical map $V\otimes V \to H^0(2D)$ and denote the image by $W$. It is known that the dimension $\dim\, W \geq 2\dim\,V-1$.

My question is that, can we characterize when the equality holds. I think that if it should be in this way (we assume that $\dim\, V \geq 4$): $\dim\, W = 2\dim\,V-1$ if and only if the image of the map defined by $V$ is a rational curve, i.e., $\varphi_V(C)$ is rational;
and $\dim\, W = 2\dim\,V$ if and only if the image of the map defined by $V$ is either a rational curve or an elliptic curve.

Comment: Do you have any evidence? What I can say right away is that your two conjectures contradict to each other: if its "iff" in the first one, it cannot be "rational" in the second.

Comment: Maybe I should say that the second one is iff the image is an elliptic curve.

Comment: Anyway, what I want to know is that, if $\dim W$ is very close to $2 \dim V -1$, can we say something about the map defined by $V$?

Comment: Is it easy to see that $\dim W\ge 2\dim V-1$? Is it in Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris? Or on some other reference? Thanks.

Comment: @quim - I believe this is in ACGH.  Isn't this just a case of the Hopf Lemma- If V,W,U are vector space over an alg. closed field and if $V\otimes W \to U$ is a non-degenerate map, then the dimension of the image is at least dim(V)+Dim(W) -1.  I don't recall if they give a proof.